# React Native Linking 'openUrl':How to select default browser?

Tags: react-native

The title says it all. I'm just curious, for example, if we have Safari and Chrome installed, how do we choose the browser for 'openUrl' method? Based on what it determines which one to open?

Thanks!

Comment: I would like to know this as well! I would like to allow the user to select among any common browsers they have installed, such as chrome, firefox, etc

Comment: I would like to know 。。。。